# android Spinner: center text vertically within spinner

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

[image: lol]

i need these spinners to vertically center the text.  i've tried stuff like this in the Spinner xml definition:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/dir_spn"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

i tried building a custom drop down layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="@style/SpinnerDropDownItem"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

styles.xml:

```
<resources>
<style name="SpinnerDropDownItem">
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">#FFFF9200</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">?android:attr/textColorHint</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">#5C5CFF</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

adapter dropdown set:

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
```

how do i get the Spinner text to center vertically?

EDIT:
it may be worth mentioning that the Activity is themed in the manifest thusly:

```
<resources>
<style name="SpeakNSpell" parent="@android:style/Theme">
    <item name="android:minHeight">68sp</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

which makes all Views at least 68sp high.  is this affecting the text inside the Spinner as well?

Comment: I would reduce it to the simplest form and go from there.  First try it without the style and fancy widget.  Make a simple TextView layout and set gravity to center_vertical and see if that works.  Also, the drop down layout is *not* the one displayed when the spinner is closed (as you are showing it).  Perhaps you need to apply your style to the layout used when the spinner is closed?

Comment: I don't see your spinner's `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Rewrite**

You seem to want to center the text vertically in the item resource, shown below, but your code examples targets the dropdown menu...

[image: Compare Layouts]

The top Spinner is the default android simple_spinner_item layout and the bottom is the same but has `android:gravity="center_vertical"` added.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

You can see that I used your Theme with the large `minHeight`. Here is a basic example to use this layout in an Adapter:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item, list);
// set whatever dropdown resource you want
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I went with the assumption that you want "CASH", "Select Product", etc from your picture centered, let me know if you where trying to do something else!

Answer (score 6):

If somebody is still having problems after setting `gravity`, try to set padding of the `Spinner`:

```
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
```

Comment: If I could up vote this 5 times, I would.  I spent hours fighting with the Spinner trying to get it to behave and honor the android:gravity="center_vertical" to no avail.  The solution was as simple as this.  I think the reason it was misbehaving was that I set the background attribute to a 9 patch.  After that, the Spinner insisted on placing text content at the top.  Thank you so much for this post.

Comment: Godspeed, peter.bartos

Answer (score 0):

In your `SpinnerAdapter` try something like this:

```
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView,parent);
       ((TextView) v).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
       return v;
}
```